# N8N Expose Oauth2 endpoints

Tags: n8n

This may seem like a dumb question, but I was wondering if it’s possible to expose N8N’s Oauth2 endpoints so that I can use them in my own back-end. I saw inside the N8N source code only endpoints inside the v1 folder are exposed as public. Is my only solution either to change the source code or handling Oauh2 in my back-end without using these N8N endpoints.

The endpoints I’m talking about are these ones:

```
oauth2CredentialController.get(
    '/auth',
```

And

```
oauth2CredentialController.get(
    '/callback',
```